# How to evaluate a classification model trained with built-in Linear Learner on Google AI Platform?

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to evaluate a classification model I've created using Google AI Platform's built-in Linear Learner. I've set 20% of the data for testing, however I don't understand where I can find and interpret the results of this test. The documentation skips this step and jumps straight into deployment.

How can I evaluate the model I've created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find this in the job's stackdriver logs. It would appear after the line that says **Performing final evaluation**

You could also use tensorboard to see the training statistics :
`tensorboard --logdir=<GCS_PATH_TO_YOUR_JOB_DIR>`

FYI : [Instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/summaries_and_tensorboard#setup) on how to setup tensorboard.